# Python: Function not returning a list when called

Tags: python, function

Following is the code for a list of 3 students whose marks have been entered and i want to calculate the individual and class average. The average function returns the correct value for individual students, however, the get_class_average function doesn't return the correct value. This is a codecademy course in python and the online compiler shows following error:
Oops, try again. get_class_average([alice]) returned 83.8666666667 instead of 91.15 as expected.
 What is wrong?There are no syntax errors.

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]
 }
 alice = {
"name": "Alice",
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
"tests": [89.0, 97.0]
 }
 tyler = {
"name": "Tyler",
"homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
"quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
"tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
  total = sum(numbers)
  total = float(total)
  return total/len(numbers)

def get_average(student):
  homework = average(student["homework"])
  quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
  tests = average(student["tests"])
  s = 0.1*homework + 0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests
  return s
def get_letter_grade(score):
  if score>=90:
     return "A"
  elif score>=80:
     return "B"
  elif score>=70:
     return "C"
  elif score>=60:
     return "D"
  else:
     return "F"
  print get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))
def get_class_average(students):
  results = []
  results.append(get_average(lloyd))
  results.append(get_average(alice))
  results.append(get_average(tyler))
  return(average(results))
```

Comment: you are missing a **return average(results)**

Comment: The course expects you to use the `students` argument, not just those fixed three students.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the print or return:

```
def get_class_average(students):
  results = []
  results.append(get_average(lloyd))
  results.append(get_average(alice))
  results.append(get_average(tyler))
  print average(results)
```

OR

```
def get_class_average(students):
  results = []
  results.append(get_average(lloyd))
  results.append(get_average(alice))
  results.append(get_average(tyler))
  return average(results)
```

Without the print, it doesn't print the result.  Without the return, it doesn't return the result.

Comment: Thanks, but i have edited the question and added the error message.

Comment: What is it supposed to be doing?  To find the average of alice, wouldn't you just use get_average(alice)?

Comment: get_class_average doesn't even use the "students" argument, why is it there?

Comment: I did.  My previous two comments still apply.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors here:

Firstly, a `return` is need at the end of the function `get_class_average()`. That's why the function does not return correctly.

Secondly, the function `get_class_average()` accepts parameter `students`. However, it seems that `students` does not make use of it.